# Is there value in posting a video of my paper presentation online?

Tags: phd, conference, presentation, audio-video-recording, backup-archiving

I am a PhD student in computer science and I have a paper accepted in a conference. One of my friends will record me presenting the paper during the conference and I was wondering if there are any benefits of uploading that video recording online for example on YouTube?

Comment: Does your conference allow you to record presentations? All that I have attended prohibit it.

Comment: @RichardErickson I am not 100% sure, but I think I saw people doing it in previous installments of the same conference.

Comment: Many IEEE conferences these days record talks themselves and put it on youtube (and embed it on the paper download page). Presumably they are seeing some value in it, but I have to admit I haven't yet watched any of the talks when downloading a paper.

Comment: The greatest value most likely will come from watching your own performance - perhaps with your advisor or someone whose presentation style you admire - to look for ways to improve your skills. But unless you intend to share the link with specific people of groups of people, it is unlikely that your talk will be "found" by anyone. What audience would you hope to reach?

Comment: @RichardErickson Without an explicit transfer of performance rights (in addition to transferring copyright to the paper), do conferences have any legal standing whatsoever to prohibit speakers from recording _their own_ talks and distributing them however they like?

Comment: @JeffE Meeting may limit attendee's behavior. For example, see [SETAC](https://msp.setac.org/general-info/meeting-policies/)'s policy: _No attendee at a SETAC annual meeting may record, film, tape, photograph, interview or use any such media during any presentation, poster display or exhibit without the express, advance approval of the executive director of SETAC North America. This policy applies to all SETAC members, nonmembers, guests and exhibitors as well as members of the print, online or broadcast media._The page I linked to also has a link about copyright.

Comment: @RichardErickson  Fair enough. So if you want to record your SETAC talk, do it at home or in your hotel room, not at the conference proper.

Comment: @JeffE I agree. However, other life science meetings have similar guideline: [Ecological Society of America](http://esa.org/ftlauderdale/social-media/). I would suggest the OP read the details for her or his conference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be sure that you are allowed to record presentations—as one of the comments indicated, many conferences prohibit such behavior.

If you are allowed to do so, it's usually for personal purposes, and public postings may be limited.

On the other hand, it may be possible for you to create your own version of a "podcast" with the talk using screen capture software. You can talk through your slides in greater detail than is possible in a typical conference presentation.

That said, I don't think there will be a huge demand for such a presentation.

Comment: I like your answer. Please feel free to include these two citations for examples of meetings banning recording talks without approval: Ecological Society of America http://esa.org/ftlauderdale/social-media/ and SETAC https://msp.setac.org/general-info/meeting-policies/